# Assign variable within condition if true

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I know you can assign a variable in a condition like this:

`if ($var = $foo)`

However I don't need to do anything in the condition itself, so I'm often left with empty brackets. Can I simply assign `$var` if `$foo` is `true` in some other way without needing to do something else later?

Also can I assign `$var` to `$foo` if `$foo` is `true` but if `$foo` is `false` do something else? Like:

```
if ($var = !$foo) {
    if ($var = !$bar) {
        //Etc...
    }
}
```

Basically I want to have more fallbacks/defaults.

Comment: Ermmmm, come again....?

Comment: You can use `if ($foo)` , this will work when foo is true.

Comment: You're not assigning "in the condition". You're assigning regardless of the value of `$foo`. So if you only want to overwrite `$var` with `$foo` in case `$foo` is *truthy*. You'll have to move the assignment. Or do something like `if ($foo && $var = $foo) {}` though the latter is really awful in my opinion.

Comment: @Yoshi My issue is more what happens _after_ the value of `$var` has been assigned. So if it failed to assign, have a fallback. The answers demonstrate what I was trying to do. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@chandresh_cool's suggestion is right but to allow multiple possiblities / fallbacks you would have to nest the ternary expressions:

```
$var = ($foo == true) ? $foo: 
       ($bar == true) ? $bar: 
       ($fuzz == true) ? $fuzz:
       $default;
```

Note: the first 3 lines end in colons not semi-colons.

However a simpler solution is to do the following:

```
$var = ($foo||$bar||$fuzz...);
```

Comment: Your simpler solution is exactly what I'm looking for. It's short, sweet and does what I need it to do: set $var to the first positive value it can find.

Comment: If you're going for the first option, please don't do the "== true", just do "$var = ($foo) ? $....."

Answer (score 5):

Although this is a very old post. Fallback logic on falsify values can be coded like this.

```
$var = $foo ?: $bar ?: "default";
```

In this case when `$foo` is a falsified value (like false, empty string, etc.) it will fall back to `$bar` otherwise it uses `$foo`.
If bar is a falsified value, it will fallback to the string `default`.

Keep in mind, that this works with falsified values, and not only `true`.

example:

```
$foo = "";
$bar = null;
$var = $foo ?: $bar ?: "default";
```

`$var` will contain the text `default` because empty strings and `null` are considered "false" values.

[update]

In php 7 you can use the new null coalescing operator: `??`, which also checks if the variable exists with isset(). This is usefull for when you are using a key in an array.

Example:

```
$array = [];
$bar = null;
$var = $array['foo'] ?? $bar ?? "default";
```

Before php 7 this would have given an `Undefined index: foo` notice. But with the null coalescing operator, that notice won't come up.

Comment: @jconder - I'm rolling back your edit to this answer. Leroy says "otherwise it uses `$foo`", but the edit you've made completely invalidates that. Leroy is intentionally using *two* ternary operators here (each with the first expression being empty), allowing for 3 possible outcomes: `$foo`, `$bar`, or `"default"`, rather than using a single ternary operator which could only return 2 possible outcomes: `$bar` or `"default"`.

Comment: Yep you're right about that, my bad, I missed the entire point of the post.

Comment: This makes if expressions a lot cleaner. I'm using this to check for a custom post type in WordPress `$is_entry = is_singular( 'myentry' ) ?: is_post_type_archive( 'myentry' ) ?: false;`. Now I can use `if ( $is_entry && $other_condition )` to determine if the current page belongs to my post type without the if expression getting too ugly.

Comment: In php7 there is a new null coalescing operator: `??`, which also checks if the variable exists like `isset()`. This is usefull for when you are using a key in an array. 
For example: `$var = $array['key'] ?? $bar ?: "default"`.  Now when the `key` in `$array` does not exists, it won't throw any errors. Because it wil also look if the `key` exists.

Answer (score 4):

Instead you can Use ternary operator like this

```
$var = ($foo == true)?$foo:"put here what you want";
```

Comment: It's still a little long-winded, but it works so I'll give you +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can assign values like this:

```
$var = $foo;
```

Setting them within an if statement is also possible, PHP will evaluate the resulting $var which you just assigned.

I dont really get your question, but you could do something like this:

```
if(!($var = $foo)){
   //something else.
}
```

Comment: Your if statement code looks like what I'm trying to do, but RobJ's answer was better. I'll still give you a +1 for it.