# PHP - Scope of assignment within if statement

Tags: php, variables, scope, variable-assignment

How do I delcare a variable in an if statment that only goes in the `if` block if the variable is not a nullish value?

Also, what is the scope of the `$var` in code like:

```
if(($var = funky()) != null) {}
```

Can I reference `$var` outside the `if` block?

Comment: `if($var = funky())` - I take it that that is pseudo code? If not, then what you're doing is assigning `=` rather than comparing `==`, unless that's what you want to do.

Comment: *"Will the code inside the if block still execute or do I need a conditional as well?"* - Yes, because it will always be considered as TRUE, since it's an assignment. Your edit: *"such as if(!empty($var = funky()))"* - only if it's not empty.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think I got you, so the variable assignment will **always** be true in this case. Which essentially makes it pointless unless I add a condition

Comment: Yes, that is what I did say :-) assignments are always equal to TRUE/set.

Comment: it won't always be true, it'll assign the return value of the function, and that'll be evaluated

Comment: ...which is what I said, just explained differently, for the latter part of the above comment.

Comment: Hey, I had to edit the question massively to more clearly state my question

Comment: *"Can I reference $var outside the if block?"* - Only if it has value. If in doubt, assign a default empty value to it, or use a ternary. You can also have a look at [Assign variable within condition if true](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16581174/1415724), if it's relevant to your question. @KolobCanyon In some cases, null != always empty.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i was referencing this: *"Will the code inside the if block still execute or do I need a conditional as well?" - Yes, because it will always be considered as TRUE, since it's an assignment.* < it won't if the function doesn't return truthy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An assignment expression in PHP returns the assigned value. From t[he documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php):

> The value of an assignment expression is the value assigned.

So if whatever `funky()` returns evaluates to something loosely equal to `null`, `$var = funky()` will evaluate to false, so the `if` block will not be executed.

Doing the assignment in the `if` condition does not affect the scope of the assigned variable, though. `$var` will be available in the current scope (inside *and* outside the if block) after the assignment statement.

For example:

```
function funky() {
    return false;
}

if(($var = funky()) != null) {
    echo 'something';
}

var_dump($var);
```

Here, you'll just see `boolean false`

---

The only way I can think of to ensure that a variable is only available inside an `if` block is to assign it there and unset it before the end of the block.

```
if (funky() != null) {  // evaluate funky() without assigning
    $var = funky();     // call funky() again to assign
    // do stuff
    unset($var);
}
```

But I can't really think of any good reason to do this.

Comment: Wow. I am surprised `$var` is available *outside* the if block

Comment: @KolobCanyon why? You haven't altered the scope at all (an if statement isn't a closure). You've basically just assigned a variable, and then wrote an if statement, except you've done it all in the same line

Comment: @billyonecan Gotcha. Did not know that. I always had tried to assign the variable and then do the if statement on the next line, but I saw some code that one lined it... which lead me to this question